# ansible Unexpected Exception: dictionary update sequence element #0

Tags: python, ansible

When i run below command

```
[ansible@] $ ansible localhost -vvv -m setup
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
```

it gives the following error

```
 ERROR! Unexpected Exception: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
    the full traceback was:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/ansible", line 92, in <module>
        exit_code = cli.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/cli/adhoc.py", line 129, in run
        inventory = Inventory(loader=loader, variable_manager=variable_manager, host_list=self.options.inventory)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
        self.parse_inventory(host_list)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 159, in parse_inventory
        group.vars = combine_vars(group.vars, self.get_group_variables(group.name))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 527, in get_group_variables
        self._vars_per_group[groupname] = self._get_group_variables(groupname, vault_password=vault_password)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 545, in _get_group_variables
        vars = combine_vars(vars, self.get_group_vars(group))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 727, in get_group_vars
        return self._get_hostgroup_vars(host=None, group=group, new_pb_basedir=new_pb_basedir, return_results=return_results)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 788, in _get_hostgroup_vars
        host_results = self._variable_manager.add_group_vars_file(base_path, self._loader)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/vars/__init__.py", line 616, in add_group_vars_file
        data = self._load_inventory_file(path, loader)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/vars/__init__.py", line 574, in _load_inventory_file
        rval.update(data)
    ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: Submit an issue on GitHub. While it doesn't guarantee a fix, at least the template there, will require you to provide the necessary information (like versions, etc.) which you didn't bother to post on SO. ・・・And there is no question you are using some old Ansible, only the question: how old.

Comment: python2.6? rather old

Comment: @Konstantin Suvorov: old but still officially supported (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_installation.html#control-machine-requirements: "Currently Ansible can be run from any machine with Python 2 (versions 2.6 or 2.7)"). @anish: which version of ansible? (`ansible --version`). Can you display full output and not just the stacktrace? (update your question instead of answering in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using ansible <2.3 and hitting [issues #18843](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/18843): there is a syntax error in one of your `group_vars` files.

Try to upgrade to more recent version of ansible and the error should show you more info about the syntax error.